# How to select several child with deference level in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How i can select all child in a parent div with deference child level in jQuery?

For example i want to get all myDiv1 input, Not myDiv2:

```
<div id="myDiv1">
   <input name="child1"/><!-- level 1 -->
   <p><input name="child2"/></p><!-- level 2 -->
   <div><p><input name="child3"/></p></div><!-- level 3 -->
</div>

<div id="myDiv2">
   <input name="child1"/><!-- level 1 -->
   <p><input name="child2"/></p><!-- level 2 -->
   <div><p><input name="child3"/></p></div><!-- level 3 -->
</div>
```

I tested $('#mydiv1 input') OR $('#mydiv1 > input') but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#mydiv1 input')` will select all `input` elements which are inside `#mydiv1` - no matter how deep.

`$('#mydiv1 > input')` will only select `input` elements which are direct children of `#mydiv1` (i.e. `child1`)

If that doesn't work for you, something else is wrong with you code.

Comment: If the `id` values really are as written in the question, the "something else" is the fact that the selectors are wrong (should be `#myDiv1`).

Comment: I make a mistake in my code, i copied original div to an other div. your answer is true :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the first level .children will only look there.

I'm not sure I'm understanding the question correctly though.